# Apache Sling upgrade Jackrabbit

Tags: jackrabbit, sling

have anyone done something like upgrading embedded jackrabbit server in Apache Sling v. 2.1?
I'm not sure if it will be compatibile with `sling.jcr.api`.
Can new version of Jackrabbit be provided as an osgi bundle or is it better to rebuild whole sling?

I cannot find nothing about that in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply upgrade the dependencies. The Sling bundles are typically backwards compatible, so just try it. If anything breaks, it's probably a bug and should be reported.